# Select the last exchange value for each currency. SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, request

Let's consider we have table of currencies. The task is to derive the last update of a price for each currency (name).

[image: ![\xxx](https://prnt.sc/uc2vyq)]

My endeavor:

```sql
SELECT name, date, price
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY name 
       ORDER BY date DESC
    ) as RN
  FROM currency
) X where RN = 1;
```

My solution virtually cover everything, except two dollar's fields:

`| USD | 2006-03-04 | 8 |` and `| USD | 2007-03-04 | 8 |`

Technically, I comprehend why does it happen. I define the `RN = 1`, which selects first row for each currency (considering that the dates for each currency are in descending order). In the problem, described above the last update occurs 2006-03-04, and generally its order is second.

However, I have no idea, how to formulate a request to choose the `MIN` of the dates in the last subgroup.

If you have an idea how to do that - I'ill be very thankful!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you want the rows where the currency changes.  If that interpretation is correct, use `lag()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, lag(name) over (order by date) as prev_name
      from currency c
     ) c
where prev_name is null or prev_name <> name;
```

Note that standard SQL has a way to simplify the `where` clause using a `NULL` safe comparison:

```
where prev_name is distinct from name
```

However, not all databases support this (or similar) syntax.

EDIT:

I think my above interpretation is incorrect.  You want the second to last row because the price does not change.  So:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, lag(price) over (partition by name order by date) as prev_price
      from currency c
     ) c
where prev_price is null or prev_price <> price;
```

Then to get one row per currency:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as seqnum
      from (select c.*, lag(price) over (partition by name order by date) as prev_price
            from currency c
           ) c
      where prev_price is null or prev_price <> price
     ) c
where seqnum = 1
```

EDIT II:

In Postgres, the last query is more simply written as:

```
select distinct on (name) c.*
from (select c.*, lag(price) over (partition by name order by date) as prev_price
      from currency c
     ) c
where prev_price is null or prev_price <> price
order by name, date desc
```